# chrome.history search vs getVisits correct work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to find url in browser history. First i used function chrome.history.getVisits. But this function show fake results, because manually i didn't find url in history. But  getVisits found this url and returned it

After i start use function chrome.history.search and it works good but very slow. I make 25 request after page load and it takes much time and slow browser. Instead of getVisits, it works very fast

So the question how i can up speed of function search? Or how can i change call function getVisits not to return fake results?

Comment: `getVisits` should work, otherwise it wouldn't be in the history API. There's probably some issue with your Chrome profile. Try it on a new Chrome user profile.

Comment: `getVisits` is work, but it returns not correct results. May be any settings to return only some type history ulrs?

Comment: There's a related issue.  http://crbug.com/538147.

Comment: chrome extension team looks super busy. so that they cannot follow up quickly.